# Thunderbird/Lightning - How to "accept" an outlook invite and have it added to my google calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, lightning

Thunderbird/Lightning - How to "accept" an outlook invite and have it added to my google calendar?

Currently, when I "accept" outlook originated events they are added to my "work" cal by default and not sure how to sync this or have this sync'ed to my google cal.

Is there a way to set lightning to add accepted events to my google cal by default, which i've set up remotely using the google provider?

Thanks -dm

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that one accepted it will send a whole load of new erroneous invitations.

The bug details from Mozilla are here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=400808

A fix to this issue with GC would be *hugely* welcome to those of us who are heavy calendar users with open source mail clients!  This issue is so significant for some of our guys I've had people wanting Outlook just so they can accept invitations :(

Comment: Is this still true? I can't figure out in this bug report maze.